# React Navigation v5 won't reset and remove previous routes

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I have a login screen which I have placed in stack. After user logs in successfully he is redirected to home screen which is a drawer screen. One of the options of drawer screen is logout, so on click of it user should be logged out. Following is my code for logout screen. I am just showing a progress bar of logout screen in ui but in `useEffect` hook, I am calling the following method

```
navigation.navigate({index: 0, routes: [{name: LOGIN_SCREEN}]});
```

but I get an error saying `You need to specify name or key when calling navigate with an object as the argument` and I am redirected to home screen. when I restart my app completely then only it moves to login screen. I am passing the right value for name key.

My Navigation stack looks something as follows

```
 <Stack.Navigator>

      <Stack.Screen
        name={LOGIN_SCREEN}
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
     <Stack.Screen
        name={HOME_STACK_SCREEN}
        component={DrawerStack}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />...
```

My drawer component as follows

```
<Drawer.Navigator
      drawerStyle={{backgroundColor: BLUE_COLOR_1}}
      drawerContentOptions={{labelStyle: {color: '#FFF'}}}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={HOME_SCREEN}
        component={Home}
        options={{
         ...
        }}
      />
     <Drawer.Screen
        name={LOGOUT_SCREEN}
        component={Logout}
        options={{
         ...
        }}
      />
```

Comment: how are you navigating from Login Stack to Drawer, with reset?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to reset then you need to use `reset`, not `navigate`:

```js
navigation.reset({
  routes: [{ name: LOGIN_SCREEN }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I get a dialog saying Invariant violation. Maximum depth exceeded after replacing navigate with reset

Comment: this might be related to this https://github.com/react-navigation/hooks/issues/35

Comment: `LOGIN_SCREEN` should be in quotes

Comment: depends on if it's a variable or a string, it's a variable in OP

Answer (score 16):

In react-navigation v5. You can reset navigation like this

```
import { CommonActions } from "@react-navigation/native";

this.props.navigation.dispatch(
     CommonActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{ name: "LOGIN_SCREEN" }],
    })
);
```